# How to specify type of JSON value?

Tags: ruby, json, api

I'm using Grape on Padrino to make a test API for my mobile app.

How can I specify the type of my JSON object?

Here is how i do it, but every returned value is a String:

```
module Acme
  module Api
    class Ping < Grape::API
      format :json

       get '/user/112132a08s245c/availability_list' do
            {
                "availability_list"=> [
              {
                :type=> "OOO",
                :from_date=> "21-12-2004",
                :to_date=> "21-23-2007",
                :all_day=> "false"

                },
              {
                :type=> "WFH",
                :from_date=> "21-12-2004",
                :to_date=> "21-23-2007",
                :all_day=> "false"
                }

              ]
      }
      end


       get '/user/112132a08s245c/issues' do
            {
                "issues"=> [
              {
                :issure_id=> "1ab300co221",
                :title=> "No water",
                :description=> "No water in kitchen",
                :severity=> "low",
                "location" => {
                  :lat => "37.4224764",
                  :lng => "-122.0842499"
                }

                },
              {
                :issure_id=> "1ab300co222",
                :title=> "No fire",
                :description=> "No fire in kitchen",
                :severity=> "low",
                "location" => {
                  :lat => "37.4224764",
                  :lng => "-122.0842499"
                }

                }

              ]
      }
      end

    end
  end
```

Comment: JSON is a string. It's a string representation of your data structures. `'{"x": 5}`' is a string.

Comment: You need to read [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org) I think. JSON serializes data into a string because objects can't be transferred between disparate languages. When it sees the incoming string the parser knows it has to convert it back to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'json'

foo = {'a' => 1}
foo.class # => Hash
str = JSON[foo] # => "{\"a\":1}"
str.class # => String
bar = JSON[str] # => {"a"=>1}
bar.class # => Hash
```

You need to read [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org). JSON serializes data into a string because objects can't be transferred between disparate languages. When it sees an object the parser serializes it into a string. When the incoming string is received and passed on to the parser, it knows it has to convert the string back to an object.